# change a property from one class in a different class swift (specifically a UILabel)

Tags: ios, uitableview, class, uilabel, swift2

I'm trying to change the text of a UILabel in a UITableView (a property of one class,) from inside another class, but I'm having trouble. The code looks like this (The problem is at the end, in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of myDataSource)

The View Controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    //needed so data from myDataSource is retained by ViewController and not just thrown away
    let importedDataSource = myDataSource()


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myTableView.dataSource = myDataSource()
        myTableView.delegate = myDataSource()

    }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       {super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()}

}
```

The UITableViewDataSource and Delegate

```
class myDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    let cellIdentifier = "myTableViewCell"
    let myArray = ["Label one", "Label two", "Label three"]

    //MARK: TableViewDataSource
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
     {return 1}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {return myArray.count}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myTableViewCell

        cell.myCellLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
    //MARK:TableView Delegate
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
     {  
          //This Line Here returns the error
          ViewController().myLabel.text = "test"
          //I want the end product to be ViewController().myLabel.text = myArray[indexPath.row], but left it as "test" just to simplify and isolate the error
     }

}
```

(there's also a UITableViewCell class called myTableViewCell, but I left it out to be shorter)

Running returns "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" upon selecting one of the rows. How should I call myLabel so as to avoid this problem? I've tried hooking it up as an @IBOutlet inside myDataSource by ctrl-dragging it from the storyboard, but as I expected, it only lets me connect it to the view controller.

sorry, the code is a bit confusing with the two similarly named labels. I'm trying to call the myLabel var created in the ViewController (first piece of code), not the myCellLabel created in myTableViewCell (not shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing the message "***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***" is because you are trying to assign a value to a property of `nil`.

In the implementation of your UITableViewDelegate method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` the statement:

`ViewController().myLabel.text = "test"`

1. creates a new instance of your `ViewController` class (that is what `ViewController()` does)
2. accesses the `myLabel` property of the new instance (recall that in your declaration of the class you defined this property to be of type `UILabel!`, an implicitly-unwrapped optional `UILabel`, and implicitly-unwrapped optionals begin life as `nil` until they are assigned a value)
3. tries to assign "test" to the `text` property of `myLabel` - but as we just noted, `myLabel` is `nil` and this is why you are receiving the error message

**EDIT**

In an effort to assist you in your stated goal of "**trying to change the text of a UILabel**" (that label being the property `myLabel` of your `ViewController` instance), the route I would recommend is:

- have your `ViewController` class adopt the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol
- implement your `UITableViewDelegate` protocol methods inside of your `ViewController` class, where they will have direct access to the `myLabel` property

once you've done this, your implementation of that delegate method (now residing inside of your `ViewController` class) would look like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {  
  myLabel.text = myTableView.dataSource.myArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

...and while this will work, even this can be improved - I recommend you check out Apple's [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1)

furthermore, unless there is a compelling reason not to, I also recommend that you have your `ViewController` class act as your `UITableViewDataSource` - from the Table View Programming Guide: "***[t]he class creating the table view typically makes itself the data source and delegate by adopting the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols***" (see this [section](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW4))

Comment: Thanx! that helps. But if I were trying to clean up a crowded ViewController class and wanted the delegate and datasource separate from the view controller, what would be the simplest way to set the Label (created in the view controller) from inside the datasource/delegate class?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the actual table view cell that was tapped in order to access it's variables. Use `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It'll look something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if let myCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? myTableViewCell {
        myCell.myLabel.text = "test"
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, the code is a bit confusing with the two similarly named labels. I'm trying to call the myLabel var created in the ViewController (first piece of code), not the myCellLabel created in myTableViewCell (not shown). The label is outside the TableView but I want it to change to the text in myCellLabel, like a dropdown menu that you select something and your selection becomes the label's text